# Process forms within a lightbox

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to display a data collection form inside of a lightbox on Drupal 7. The form is being generated with custom code.

Forms support for Colorbox 2.x has been removed according to the documentation. I went ahead anyway and installed colorbox2 and colobox_node; the form WAS displayed correctly. However, any attempt to process the form resulted in a page of garbage text.

Next attempt is lightbox2. That is a little more forgiving. The form was displayed correctly. And when "submit" is pressed, the form processes. However, if any validation occurs, (resulting in a redisplay of the form), the form is redisplayed outside of the lightbox.

Question is how can one display and perform processing of a form within a lightbox on Drupal 7?

Comment: take a look at sample in ctools module folder http://cgit.drupalcode.org/ctools/tree/ctools_ajax_sample/ctools_ajax_sample.module

Comment: Have you used it it?   That was my third choice in paths to go down. https://www.drupal.org/project/modal_forms

Comment: Yes, it will be a good solution if you don't want to write code yourself